# Can the Fixed-Term Parliaments Act be bypassed by a simple bill?

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-commons

The Fixed-Term Parliaments Act sets out the conditions for calling a general election, including a two-thirds majority vote in the House for an early general election.

But could a bill be presented to the House calling for a general election that could pass on a simple majority?

Comment: Passage in the commons by a simple majority is not sufficient for a bill to become law.  The house of lords must also be involved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but such a bill would have to be approved by both the Commons and the Lords (by a simple majority). Or if the Lords didn't approve it, the commons could force it through under the Parliament Act, but there would still be possibly a substantial delay.

The FTPA allows the PM to call a general election without consulting the Lords providing he or she has the votes of 2/3 of Parliament.

Notwithstanding the implicit ability of any Parliament to repeal part or all of any previous act of parliament, the FTPA sets out intentions. It is intended that a 2/3 majority should be required before a government calls an election so that the government would normally need the support of opposition parties. The FTPA describes how the process should go in the normal procedure, not how the procedure should be changed in exceptional situations.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Any Act of Parliament can be amended or repealed by a later Act of Parliament.

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_sovereignty):

> No Parliament can bind a future parliament (that is, it cannot pass a law that cannot be changed or reversed by a future Parliament).

Comment: So, why did they bother with the two-thirds number?

Comment: @Ben: the idea is that an early general election should only occur if there is cross-party support. If there is, then all it takes is a single motion in the Commons (with the 2/3 majority). Passing a new Act of Parliament takes longer, requires the agreement of the Lords - and can be amended. The danger of opposition amendments makes this unattractive to the current government.

Comment: Ah. Can amendments to a bill be blocked?

Comment: With a majority vote, yes - but the current government doesn't have one.

Comment: If an unwanted amendment is introduced by an opponent and is likely to pass, can the government terminate the progress of the bill (that they introduced)?

Comment: @Ben: a government with a majority certainly can, as it can simply decline to put it on the schedule. However, if the opposition are able to gain control of the schedule, then the govt may not be able to do that - in the Commons. In the Lords, the procedures are different, and no party has a majority, so I'm not sure; but it seems unlikely, as the Lords were content to pass the Benn bill.

Comment: Thanks. Given that the Benn Bill made it to law essentially without any pushing from the executive, a speculative attempt at a one page GE bill would be costless, because clearly the opposition can do what they like anyway?

Comment: @Ben at the moment the government *wants* a general election and the opposition does not.  So if anyone would try to bypass the FTPA with a new act of parliament it would be the government rather than the opposition.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my meaning. If the government want a GE, and they are thinking about a one-page bill, they need to weigh the cost/risk of possible amendments. My question is: given that the opposition appear to be able to pass whatever law they like _anyway_, the shot-to-nothing attempt at a GE appears costless?

Comment: @Ben A somewhat simplified way of thinking about the situation is to believe there are three groups: hard leavers (like e.g. Gove), soft leavers (e.g. May) and remainers (e.g. Clarke). None of the groups can get their way in Parliament because the two other groups will unite to stop them. Unless it's something like the Benn Bill which aims to _prevent_ a hard Brexit. Collectively Parliament doesn't know what it wants but knows what it doesn't want.